# How do websites play audio in the header continuously on url changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, soundcloud

Websites like soundcloud and hypem allow you to traverse along their site. The URL in the address bar changes when you click around however the music never stops playing how is that possible? AJAX doesn't change the URLs. It's like I start playing the flash on the page and it runs in the header at the same time.

I have a music blog that has embeds from youtube and soundcloud is it possible to do this on my site? If so, what should I research/learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They catch the changing url in JavaScript and modify the page content dynamically without actually reloading the page. It's the same "physical" page all along. A popular library function that handles this is [Angular's routing capabilities](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24route).